# value.length not working as expected when backspacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, char, textarea

I'm trying to get the characters of a textarea using javascript, and it works fine when you're typing text inside the textarea, but when you're using backspacing, it gives the wrong length of characters.

```
<textarea id = 'textarea' onkeydown = "adjust()"></textarea>

<script>

function adjust() {

var length = document.getElementById("textarea").value.length+1;
alert("length: "+length);

} //end of function adjust()
</script>
```

**For example:**

Say, you start when 25 characters in the textarea. Then when you use backspace once:

It alerts: 26 characters;
Use backspace again, and it will alert: 25 characters;
Then, 24, 23, 22, 21.

Which isn't true, since it should be showing 24,23,22,21,20, and 19 instead. Why is it doing that, and how would we fix it?

Comment: when the function `adjust` is called, the backspace default behavior (i.e. deletes previous character) has not been applied. So the 25th character is still there, and in the function 'adjust' you are adding the length by one BEFORE that 25th character is deleted.

Comment: @DPac Oh. I see. So it calls the function BEFORE it delete the character. Damn. How would we fix this?

Comment: Try "keyup" instead. Or the "input" event. Note that key events are not triggered when the user changes the field via the mouse or Edit menu.

Comment: P. S. With "keydown" it's not just the backspace key that gives you problems: the field's value won't change immediately for *any* key, which is why your adjust() function had to add 1 in the first place. Pressing ctrl or shift would also mess up your count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
function adjust() {

var key = event.keyCode;
if (key == 8 || key == 46) {
var length = document.getElementById("textarea").value.length-1;
} //end of if (key == 8 || key == 46)
else {
var length = document.getElementById("textarea").value.length+1;
}
alert("length: "+length);

} //end of function adjust()
```

Comment: Key 8 and 46 is backspace and delete.

Comment: What if I press ctrl or shift?

Comment: @nnnnnn It would increase the count by 1, but not permanently. I'm okay with that.

Comment: @nnnnnn This will be use in conjunction with a function that auto-adjust the height of a textarea depending on how many characters there are in the textarea, so ctrl or shift is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to the fact that you're listening to the `onkeydown` event, and the removal of each character doesn't register until after the backspace key is up again?